# C#, should I store Bitmap size separately?

Tags: c#, bitmap, size

My application works with large amount of images and I have to store some calculated info about each one. Frequently I need to get image's size for my calculations (sometimes without need to load original image).
What is better: each time to load needed Bitmap and to get its size, or at first get the size and store it in a Size object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said yourself "without need to load original image" - so sure get the compiled info for your bitmaps and store them. If you use a DB then you can for example store just your infos and the path to your bitmap. Only load big pictures if you really need them.

Comment: "sometimes" I need to load them. I'm not using any DB, I store all my info in a List. Would it be efficient to store Size for all images in memory, when I can Load/Get size/Dispose my Bitmap? There are near 500 images.

Comment: Efficient in what way? Runtime - no it's inefficient. Memory - yes it's more efficient to load/dispose them. But normal memory is cheaper than cpu-time so I would not advise this. You will waste a lot time to load hole pictures and the GC will be quite busy as well if you do this very often. - And you can still load them as soon as you need them. 500 times the information to store the path + some calculated information is almost nothing . Of course if you don't persist this data in any way you have to do it at starttime for each bitmap - in this case use some lazy-loading technique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm convinced. I think I'll continue store Bitmap's size separately. Thanks a lot!